# Finding an iframe within another iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the `id` of the parent, but not the child `iframe`.

Is there a way to return the `iframe` within the parent `iframe`?

Or, all `iframe`s within a particular `iframe`?

Using jQuery to find element with `$('iframe')` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `iframe`'s `src` attribute has the same domain, protocol and port, you are set. If not, you can't do anything because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Assuming you are not violating the policy...

#### Regular JavaScript

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0],
    iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument,
    internalIframes = iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
```

You need to use the `||` short circuit evaluation exploit as IE is different.

#### jQuery

```
var internalIframes = $('iframe:first').contents().find('iframe');
```

Comment: +1 (Relative jQuery newbie) I've been trying to extract a dynamically-generated `<svg>` within a dynamically-generated (and randomly-named) `<iframe>`. Worked a charm (luckily SOP doesn't apply since there is no `src` attribute - the frame's filled with a JS API).

Answer (score 0):

var childFrames = frames['parentId'].frames

Make that recursive and start from top.frames might suit your needs as well... and has a lot less of the DOM heavy "getElementsByTagName"

or if you are in the child i frame but you just need to get a handle on the frame, this gets you the id: window.frameElement.id

**only tested in IE :(